# SwiftUI VideoPlayer full screen dismiss button missing on iOS 16+

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am using a `.fullScreenCover` to present a `VideoPlayer` view. On iOS 15 and below, doing so shows the close button in the top-left, like below:

[image]

But on iOS 16, it doesn't seem to appear.

[image]

Code is below:

```
.fullScreenCover(
        isPresented: $showVideoSheet,
        onDismiss: {
            selectedVideo = nil
        },
        content: {
            if let video = selectedVideo {
                VideoPlayerView(video: video)
            }
        }
    )
```

`VideoPlayerView` is below:

```
struct VideoPlayerView: View {

    @StateObject var model: VideoPlayerViewModel
    let video: VideoModel

    init(video: VideoModel) {
        self._model = StateObject(wrappedValue: VideoPlayerViewModel(video: video))
        self.video = video
    }

    var body: some View {
        if let player = model.player {
            VideoPlayer(player: player)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
        }
    }
}
```

The view model just loads the AVPlayer etc.

Any suggestions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73856398/avplayer-close-button-doesnt-work-on-ios-16?noredirect=1#comment130413202_73856398 Potential iOS bug maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your own close button.

```
@State var shouldShowVideoPlayer = false

var body: some View {
    Text("Example")
    .fullScreenCover(
        isPresented: $shouldShowVideoPlayer,
        onDismiss: {
            selectedVideo = nil
        },
        content: {
            ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
                if let video = selectedVideo {
                    VideoPlayerView(video: video)
                }

                Button {
                    shouldShowVideoPlayer = false
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "xmark")
                }
                .background(Color.white)
                .padding(20)
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks, seems like this is the only way to go at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

I'm facing the exact same situation and I solved it similarly to what Tamás suggested. I added a close button only for versions starting at iOS 16, given that former versions already present the button.
Also, I tried to design the button similarly to the sound button already existing on the top rightmost side of the screen which now doesn't contain a surface around it.

```
VideoPlayer(player: AVPlayer(playerItem: AVPlayerItem(asset: asset))) {
    if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Button {
                    canOpenVideo = false
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "xmark")
                        .resizable()
                        .renderingMode(.template)
                        .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
                .padding()
                
                Spacer()
            }
            
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a hint: adding `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)` instead of a VStack and HStack with Spacers will keep the code clean and readable.

Answer (score 3):

You can create player using **UIViewControllerRepresentable** instead **VideoPlayer**.

```
struct YourView: View {
    var body: some View {
       VideoPlayerView(player: AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "your_url")!))
    }
}

struct VideoPlayerView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    let player: AVPlayer

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> AVPlayerViewController {
        let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
        controller.player = player

        return controller
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AVPlayerViewController, context: Context) {

    }
}
```