# AVPlayer: Close button doesn't work on iOS 16

Tags: swift

I have an issue on iOS 16, the close button doesn't dismiss the AVPlayer as usually, but it's working on iOS 12.

Do you have any idea of what I'm missing?

```
func didTapOnPlay(url: URL) {
    let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
    playerViewController.player = player
    
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(playerDidReachEndNotificationHandler),
        name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification"),
        object: player.currentItem)
    
    router.present(playerViewController, animated: false) { [weak self] in
        self?.playerViewController.player?.play()
    }
}
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a close button in your code. Can you add the rest of the code?

Comment: Thanks for your help.

I just initialise an AVPlayerViewController (playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()) before calling the function didTapOnPlay

I'm not configuring close button because is already set on AVPlayerViewController but when I can click on it nothing happens on iOS 16 (the dismiss work as expected on iOS 15 - 12)

Should have to configure the close button ?

Answer (score 3):

Before:

I think it's a bug from iOS 16 because when I set the animated parameter as true, it works

```
router.present(playerViewController, animated: true) { [weak self] in
        self?.playerViewController.player?.play()
    }
```

Edit:

It's fixed on iOS 16.1